# displaying div from webpage with simple_html_DOM

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am trying to display some content from a webpage using curl and [simple_html_DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) whenever i echo the content it is just an array how to i get it to actually show the html content?

```
<?php
echo ("hello");

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://catalog.hastingsfilter.com/startautoapps.html");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://catalog.hastingsfilter.com/startautoapps.html");

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
//write contents of $result to file
$File = "page.txt";
$fh = fopen($File, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);
//turn file into dom object
$page = file_get_html("page.txt");
$div = $page->find('div[id=columnright]');
echo $div;

?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the **inner < iframe>** is messing the query.
Im not sure why simple html dom behave like that..
why not changing the query into:

```
$div = $page->find("iframe[name='main2']");
echo $div[0]->innertext;
```

**EDITED:**

you can change the **.src** attribute like this:

```
$page = file_get_html("page.txt");
...
$page->find("iframe[name='main2']",0)->src = "foo";
$thehtml = $page->save();
```

by the way, i called directly the **< iframe>** source and also got
a no-server found..

Comment: ok i got it to display using outertext...but the call it is making inside of the iframe is using my url instead of the site that im getting the info from so all I get is page cannot be found on server message

Comment: is there a way to change an attribute before I echo the variable for example change the src on the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you might have to use

```
$div->innertext;
```

to get the content of the div.